# Directional derivative of a Lipschitz functions exists a.e.

Tags: measure-theory, derivatives, lipschitz-functions

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ be any Lipschitz function. We know that it is differentiable almost everywhere (which is basically [Radamacher's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rademacher%27s_theorem) in one -dimension). I want to prove the Radamacher's theorem in dimension $n$. The proof that I was reading can be found [here.](http://www.math.jyu.fi/research/reports/rep100.pdf) On page 21, it is written that using Fubini's theorem we conclude that the directional derivative of $f$  in the direction $v$ exists a.e.

[image]

I am unable to understand how Fubini's theorem is applied here to make this conclusion.

Comment: It is a bit of a leap. See: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2052760/on-the-use-of-fubinis-theorem-in-the-proof-of-rademachers-theorem/2070614. Essentially the need for fubini is in the term a.e. Here, a.e. refers to the $\mathbb{R}^n$ product measure, so some care must be taken to get the correct result.

Comment: Okay thank you.